# How to have patches "belong" to turtle

Tags: netlogo

I am brand new to Netlogo and am coding a world with caching animals. They will go to their caches (I set them as blue patches) if their energy value falls below 10. They can find these caches based on a random 'memory' value given to them which is used as an in-radius value. That way, they will face and go towards a cache within their in-radius memory if they are about to die. I am starting to incorporate a home-base system where the turtle remains in a smaller area with their own caches. Does anyone know how I can make a patch belong to an individual turtle? This would allow turtles to have their specific caches in their territory. I have looked into using links and breeds, but links are only between turtles and making the individual breeds for the 50+ turtles at a time seems ineffective and complex. I apologize I don't have any code attempting to have a cache (patch) belong to a turtle, I don't know where to start. Any ideas?

Comment: When someone says "I don't know where to start", I usually offer the following advice: You may be trying to learn too much all at once by writing a big program all at once. Write a really small program; get it working; attempt to make a very small improvement to it, and get that working; and so on. If at any point you get stuck, come here, show your code, and ask a specific question about it. Never stray more than a short distance from working code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a turtle to remember anything (patches or income or anything else), then you need to assign a variable in a `turtles-own` statement and then `set` the value appropriately. Here's some example code fragments. They won't work, and you actual code would likely look a lot different because you will need some design about the conditions under which a cache will be assigned, but they show you what a variable solution looks like.

```
turtles-own
[ my-caches
]

set my-caches (patch-set my-caches patch-here)  ; code when a turtle finds a new cache site
```

If you want a patch that belongs to a turtle to make that patch unavailable to other turtles, then also set up a patch variable to store its owner.

```
patches-own
[ my-owner
]

ask turtles
  [ if [my-owner] of patch-here = nobody [set my-caches (patch-set my-caches patch-here)]
    ask patch-here [set my-owner myself]
  ]
```

I suggest you do several NetLogo tutorials, then look at some library models (and understand them) before starting your own model. You need to understand basic concepts like turtles/patches, variables, ticks before trying to build a model.